# How do variables behave when accessed among different threads in C?

Tags: c, multithreading, memory, runtime

Suppose I have two threads which run in parallel, one of them keeps a static array of x elements which it updates constantly every 100 ms. The other thread has access to a 'IsIn'' function which returns 1 if a certain element is present in said array.

My question is, is there a risk that when calling the IsIn function the array is being updated at the same time by the update function and could give an erroneous result? How does the managment of the memory allocated to that array actually work? Is there a way to prevent this problem?

Comment: Yes, what you're describing is called a race condition. Generally if you want to be sure that one thread doesn't interfere with another you something like a "lock" to block one thread until the other is finished.

Comment: In the example you describe, you're updating the array in one thread but only reading it in the other. If you accept that reading the array might not always be the most up-to-date, then you can go ahead and do so without troubling yourself with locks. If it has to be up-to-date, then you need to use a lock.

Comment: There is a second problem - The returned result could be invalid *anyway* if the array is modified a nanosecond after the function returns.

Comment: @SimonGoater I can accept that, for example, the array is not up to date. Basically the update function does nothing else than push the last element of the array out, shift every element by one and load one element in position 0. So for the purpose of the IsIn function it should be ok

Comment: The name, `IsIn` doesn't really make sense in the context you describe because it cannot tell you whether or not the target element _is_ in the array. It can only tell you whether or not the target _was_ in the array at a certain, poorly-defined instant in time. Better call the function, `WasIn` instead.

Comment: P.S., The answer that you accepted "solves" the problem by giving each thread its own, distinct array to play with so that no data are shared between the threads. But usually, when people ask questions like yours, they're looking for ways to safely and meaningfully _share_ data. I'm just asking, which "solution" are you really looking for?

Comment: @SolomonSlow I would like to get to a solution where I can access the array in Thread 1 from through the IsIn function or even a simple Get function, from Thread 2, in a way that I can be sure that at the time that I call one of these functions in Thread 2, the array where my data is stored is not being updated and changed mid-call, which could cause some wanted results. I voted the answer because even though it didnt solve the specific problem it was the only answer and it is still insightful to me. If an actual solution comes through it goes without saying that that will be my accepted answe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to...access the array in Thread 1 from through the `IsIn` function or even a simple `Get` function, from Thread 2, in a way that I can be sure that at the time that I call one of these functions in Thread 2, the array...is not being updated and changed mid-call, which could cause some [un]wanted results.

**Unwanted Results**

In C, The only possible "unwanted results" are the results that *you* don't want. As far as the C runtime is concerned, an array is just a chunk of memory, and the runtime does not care at all what you do to it.*

The kind of "result" that most of us don't want is when there is some kind of *structure* to the data in the array such that some possible configurations are "valid" and other configurations are "invalid." It often is not possible for a thread to change the data from one valid state to another without temporarily putting it into an invalid state.

In that case, the basic remedy is to use a [*mutex*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(computer_science)) to protect the data. A mutex does two things:

1. It has two states; "locked" and "unlocked," and it never allows more than one thread to lock the mutex at the same time, and
2. It [*synchronizes*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronization_(computer_science)) the threads that lock and unlock it. That is to say, the `lock` and `unlock` actions define moments in time that can be compared between threads.

**Synchronization**

[Synchronization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronization_(computer_science)) is a Big Deal. You asked,

> is there a risk that when calling the IsIn function the array is being updated *at the same time* by the update function and could give an erroneous result?

If event A happens in thread 1 and event B happens in thread 2 when there is no synchronization between the two threads, then there is no meaningful answer to the question "which event happened first?" There is no meaningful answer to, "did they happen at the same time?"
But, if thread 1 only causes event A while it has some mutex locked, and thread 2 only causes B while it has *the same mutex* locked, then we know that the events could not possibly have happened at the same time. We then can reason about, or write code to prove, which event happened first.

**Using a Mutex**

So, if thread 1 updates structured data, and we want to ensure that thread 2 will never see the data in an invalid state, we do this:

```C
#include <pthread.h>

pthread_mutex_t mutex;

// During program startup, before creating the threads;
if (pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL) != 0) { 
    fprintf(stderr, "\n mutex init failed\n"); 
    exit(1); 
    }

// In thread 1;
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
...update the shared data...
...Don't forget to always leave the data in a valid state...
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

// In thread 2;
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
...use the shared data, confident that it *must* be valid...
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
```

This guarantees that thread 2 will never use the data while thread 1 is part-way done updating it. If thread 2 tries to lock the mutex while thread 1 already has it locked, the `pthread_mutex_lock()` call in thread 2 simply will not return until after thread 1 unlocks the mutex.

**Who Goes First?**

My example *DOES NOT* prevent thread 2 from grabbing the mutex *before* thread 1 does its update. The mutex, when used in this way, only guarantees that thread 2 will see valid data. But thread 2 could see either the new valid state, or the older valid state. You cannot use a mutex to control the order in which the threads do their thing.†

If you need threads to "meet up," "take turns," "wait for each other," or in any other way to control the order in which they do stuff, that's a higher level of synchronization, and it should be the topic of a different question.

---

* The same is not true in some programming languages (e.g., Java) where an "array" is a structured object that can grow at run-time or, be moved by a garbage collector. In such languages, even if *you* don't care what is in the array, you still can mess up the run-time system if threads access it without adequate synchronization.

† Lots of questions on this site from newbies who *thought* they could use mutexes to control some sequence of operations between threads. Sometimes it looks inviting to try, but it never works.

Comment: Thank you, it was a very insightful answer

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, is there a risk that when calling the IsIn function the array is being updated at the same time by the update function and could give an erroneous result?

Yes.

> How does the managment of the memory allocated to that array actually work?

Assuming `static`, it is allocated once and placed in the `.bss`/`.data` section. It will get initialized before main is called, i.e. long before the thread callbacks are executed.

Should multiple threads access the same part of the array at the same time, race condition bugs will occur.

> Is there a way to prevent this problem?

There's an oddball feature of C which can be used here, namely the storage class specifier `_Thread_local`. This means that an array declared as `_Thread_local int arr[] = ...` will only be valid within that given thread and only for as long as that thread is executing. Should the thread callback finish, the array turns invalid.

Another option is to declare the array on the caller side, then pass a pointer to the array to each thread, as well as directives of which parts of the array each thread is supposed to access, ensuring they never work with overlapping areas of it. That's what libraries like OpenMP do for you - creating parallel execution of a loop in the main thread.

And the final optional is protection/synchronization mechanisms: semaphores, mutex, critical sections etc shared between the threads.